# ASC to TIFF Conversion and File Merging using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

I am using ModelBuilder. I would like to:

1. Convert catalog ASC files to TIFF format.
2. Merge TIFF files into a single file.

I am able to accomplish the first step successfully, but I'm struggling with the second one.

Is it possible to perform these tasks in ModelBuilder?

I started with something like this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, drag and drop the Mosaic to New Raster tool from ArcToolbox into your model.  Connect the desired tiff files to the newly added tool.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting, but this is important. The goal is to merge the entire catalog into a single raster.

Comment: The model you show would be an embedded sub-model in a master model where the exposed output of collect values becomes the input to the tool that @GBG mentions.